# Filtering a set of items by data

Tags: jquery

Say if've got a set of items with some data on them like this:

```
<li data-filtro="website, web app"><a href="trabajos.php?id=84"><img src="imgs/thumbs/item_tn_84.jpg" /></a></li>
<li data-filtro="website, banners"><a href="trabajos.php?id=131"><img src="imgs/thumbs/item_tn_131.jpg" /></a></li>
<li data-filtro="publicidad"><a href="trabajos.php?id=22"><img src="imgs/thumbs/item_tn_22.jpg" /></a></li>
<li data-filtro="publicidad"><a href="trabajos.php?id=45"><img src="imgs/thumbs/item_tn_54.jpg" /></a></li>
```

And to filter some of the by their data content matching the value of a variable named 'valor', I'd like to do something like

```
var $set = $('li').filter(function(index){
    return $(this).data('filtro').indexOf(valor) > -1;
});
```

But somehow I can't make it work ... do you guys have two minutes to open my eyes in this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What error(s) do you get (what does can't make it work mean)? What is valor set to?

Comment: It says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a different solution, and maybe that's not what you're looking for, but  you can use a selector for that:

```
$('li[data-filtro*="' + valor + '"]') //this should return all the elements you want.
```

Comment: Well, for some reason, it doesn't work .. 
    Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ['data-filtro*=website']

Comment: My bad, had a problem with the `"` and the `'`. Fixed the example, should work now.

Comment: Well, that was it. It actually filters all elements which match the value. Thank you so much @Deleteman!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('li').each(function(){

        return $(this).data('filtro').indexOf(valor) > -1;
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Kanishka. I was trying something of the like before .. 
var $set = $('li').filter(function(index){ return $(this).data('filtro').indexOf(valor) > -1; });
But I guess it never went through each of the elements ..

Comment: I've tried your proposal, and it still comes out with the indexOf exception from before ..

Comment: did u try to alert $(this).data('filtro')

Comment: i edited my answer , please check, and alert the value of valor